# How to Keep Google Map Marker in the center while the map is dragged using AGM?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I've used AGM (Angular Google Maps) in my Ionic Project to display Google Maps in my project, but I want the marker to keep in the center of the map while the map is dragged. Can I make that using AGM? Let me know if I make any mistakes. Thank you.

Here's my snippet. So far, I've used `dragend` method according to [AGM Docs](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmmarker).

**map.component.html**

```
<agm-map
      #agmMap
      [style.height.px]="height"
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [usePanning]="true"
      (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"
    >
<agm-marker
        [iconUrl]="{
          url:
            'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png',
          anchor: { x: 14.5, y: 28 },
          scaledSize: {
            width: 30,
            height: 30
          }
        }"
        [latitude]="lat"
        [longitude]="lng"
        [markerDraggable]="true"
        (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"
      ></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**map.component.ts**

```
setNewCenter(latitude, longitude) {
    this.lat = latitude;
    this.lng = longitude;
    this.getAddress(this.lat, this.lng);
  }
public mapReady(map) {
    map.addListener("dragend", () => {
      this.setNewCenter(map.getCenter().lat(), map.getCenter().lng());
    });
  }
```

Here's the result when I use `dragend`, you can check it here ->
https://ibb.co/9qVcLN5

When I used `drag` instead of `dragend` it will be like this below.
[image: drag demo]

Comment: What about a description of the problem? What doesn't work? Have you looked at the available events in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map)?  What about using `drag` instead of `dragend`?

Comment: Why not just use `drag`? According to the docs, `drag` stands for `This event is repeatedly fired while the user drags the map`.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to use the "drag", but the marker is still in the previous place then teleported to the center when I drag the map (it's not stayed at the center when I drag it)

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've added an update to my question. I've added some demos what I've tried so far

Comment: @NicholasD, I've added some updates to my question, hope you can understand it clearly

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. **Not** screenshots or links to a web page. If you can't produce this in a stack snippet, you should be able to do so in a codesandbox, codepen or alike.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drag` event of the map in conjunction

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Keep marker in map centre</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                const latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 51.495072, -0.100319 );
                const options = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center:latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                
                let marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:latlng,
                    map:map
                });
                
                google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'drag', e=>{
                    marker.setPosition( map.getCenter() )
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Proof of concept Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/juw7fpsv/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need the solution using the AGM library (Angular Google Maps), because my project uses that library, but I will consider using this too.